# GPS Location returns always null

Tags: android, geolocation, android-location

I am trying to access `gps` location in my activity but always getting `null` when calling `getLastKnownLocation` of `LocationManager` class. I have added following permissions also.My GPS in enabled and I have no internet on the device.Kindly guide me what am i doing wrong

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

and also checking in code. below is my code.

```
public class MainActivity extends  AppCompatActivity implements LocationListener {
    private TextView latituteField;
    private TextView longitudeField;
    private LocationManager locationManager;
    private String provider;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        try {
            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                    != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                        2);

            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        latituteField = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextView02);
        longitudeField = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextView04);

        // Get the location manager
        locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, this);
        Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
        if (location != null){
            latituteField.setText(location.getLatitude()+"");
            longitudeField.setText(location.getLongitude()+"");
        }else{
            latituteField.setText("not found");
            longitudeField.setText("not found");
        }

    }



    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        int lat = (int) (location.getLatitude());
        int lng = (int) (location.getLongitude());
        latituteField.setText(String.valueOf(lat));
        longitudeField.setText(String.valueOf(lng));
    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Enabled new provider " + provider,
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Disabled provider " + provider,
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: Quick way to check this is open Google maps in the same phone and check if it is showing the current location

Comment: Map is giving me my correct location

Comment: Before the line " locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, this); " .You  need to check the whether gps/location settings is on your device.If it is not on means you need to make it as on .If location settings is off means then the location value may be null.

Comment: Location settings are ON, i can see location icon when my activity is on.

Comment: `Map is giving me my correct location` By using wifi. It will too if gps is not on.

Answer (score 0):

implement this in your build.gradle,

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:17.0.0'
```

Try this code. It is working fine for me..

```
package com.example.geolocation;

import android.Manifest;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import com.google.android.gms.location.FusedLocationProviderClient;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationResult;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements LocationListener {
    private TextView latituteField;
    private TextView longitudeField;
    private LocationManager locationManager;
    private String provider;
    private FusedLocationProviderClient fusedLocationClient;
    private String TAG=MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();
    LocationCallback mLocationCallback;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        try {
            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                    != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                        2);

            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        latituteField = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextView02);
        longitudeField = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextView04);

        // Get the location manager
        locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
        if (!locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER))
            Log.d(TAG, "onCreate: not enabled gps");
        else {
            LocationRequest mLocationRequest = LocationRequest.create();
            mLocationRequest.setInterval(60000);
            mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(5000);
            mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
            mLocationCallback = new LocationCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onLocationResult(LocationResult locationResult) {
                    if (locationResult == null) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "locationStatusCheck: onLocationResult null");
                        return;
                    }
                    for (Location location : locationResult.getLocations()) {
                        if (location != null) {
                            //TODO: UI updates.
                            Log.d(TAG, "locationStatusCheck: onLocationResult not null");
                            double lat = (location.getLatitude());
                            double lng = (location.getLongitude());
                            latituteField.setText(String.valueOf(lat));
                            longitudeField.setText(String.valueOf(lng));
                            Log.d(TAG, "latitudeField: " + latituteField);
                            Log.d(TAG, "longitudeField: " + longitudeField);
                        }
                    }
                }
            };
            LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(getApplicationContext()).requestLocationUpdates(mLocationRequest, mLocationCallback, null);
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        int lat = (int) (location.getLatitude());
        int lng = (int) (location.getLongitude());
        latituteField.setText(String.valueOf(lat));
        longitudeField.setText(String.valueOf(lng));
    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Enabled new provider " + provider,
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Disabled provider " + provider,
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```